# Change images in menu

Tags: javascript, image, menu

I need to swap (change) the image in `img` tag after hover and click.

I'm not good in javascript so i need help.

If some image is active (clicked) and I click on next image in menu so other images must be change to default.

```
<ul id="ourteam">  
    <li><a data-target="#user1" class="active"><img src="/img/avatars/avatar1.png" data-other-src="/img/avatars/avatar1h.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#user2"><img src="/img/avatars/avatar_t.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#user3"><img src="/img/avatars/avatar3.png" data-other-src="/img/avatars/avatar3h.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#user4"><img src="/img/avatars/avatar4.png" data-other-src="/img/avatars/avatar4h.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

add onclick  to the anchor

```
function set_anch_image(anch) {
   var imgs = document.getElementById("ourteam").getElementsByTagName("img");
   for(var i=0;imgs.length;i++) hold[i].src = "avatar"+(i+1)+".png" ;
   anch.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "avatar_t.png" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be using CSS to change the image on hover. Not to mention the fact that you can add a class on hover or click to achieve the same effect using a combination of CSS and JavaScript. However, if you need to accomplish using JavaScript alone, I would recommend using jQuery or another library that has these methods and many others already built-in. Especially if you are not so well versed in plain JavaScript.

**CSS**

This option removes the need for the image tag completely. In order to ensure that your image is displayed properly you will need to provide dimension to your LI elements within the CSS and also make the A element display: block.

```
#ourteam li a { display: block; }

#ourteam li:nth-child(1) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar1.png'); }
#ourteam li:hover:nth-child(1) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar11.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(2) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar_t.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(3) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar3.png'); }
#ourteam li:hover:nth-child(3) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar3h.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(4) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar4.png'); }
#ourteam li:hover:nth-child(4) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar4h.png'); }
```

**jQuery**

This will handle all 3 events - click, mouse enter and mouse leave. It simply swaps the values of the "src" and your "data-other-src".

```
$(function(){

    $('#ourteam img').on('click mousenter mouseleave', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        var _this = $(this),
            oldSrc = _this.attr('src'),
            newSrc = (_this.attr('data-other-src')) ? _this.attr('data-other-src') : oldSrc;

        _this.attr('src', newSrc).attr('data-other-src', oldSrc);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, we can use the hover and click events to toggle an active class to either the list item or the a. For this example, let's go with the anchor.

```
CSS

#ourteam li:nth-child(1) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar1.png'); }
#ourteam li:nth-child(1) a.active { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar1h.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(2) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar_t.png'); }
#ourteam li:nth-child(2) a.active { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar_t.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(3) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar3.png'); }
#ourteam li:nth-child(3) a.active { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar3h.png'); }

#ourteam li:nth-child(4) a { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar4.png'); }
#ourteam li:nth-child(4) a.active { background: url('/img/avatars/avatar4h.png'); }


jQuery 

$(function(){

    $('#ourteam li a').on('click mousenter mouseleave', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```